# What does this TypeScript mean with regards to useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and am learning it by setting up a new project and how I would normally do that, but with TypeScript along the way. I have this bit of React working but do not know what this means -- therefore which document I should be reading to learn up on it.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<any | null>(false);
```

Specifically the <any | null> part. This is the only new part with TypeScript but not sure how to read this. Is this saying the type is any type, else null? What are some other options I can use in place of any and null? Are there scenarios I should avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct way to type a `useState` but normally you want to avoid using `any`.

In your example you are creating some state with a default value of false.  In this case you don't really need to define the type as it will be inferred as a boolean.  Let's say that value could be null or an object, then you could define the type like so:

```
// Just an example
interface User {
  username: string
}

const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
```